# Javascript sending array with files to php

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, post, upload

So i'm sending a jquery object that contains some info about a file and the actual `$("#input").files[0]; item`.

The jquery/javascript looks something like the following:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/upload/create',
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: JSON.stringify(data),
    success: function(msg) {
        alert(msg);
    }
});
```

The data variable is a JQuery object that contains info about the uploaded file and the file itself(I think), I just passed it in the object.

Is there any way to extract and save this file on the server-side with PHP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove the `JSON.stringify()` call and you should be good. `data` should be an object, which gets converted to PHP's associative `$_POST` or `$_GET` array, `stringify` converts it to a string.

```
data: data,
```